# Need to update records between tables with matching values

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column table from another table where there are maching value between corresponding records. I have the following statement but I need help with the syntax.

```
 UPDATE table_a
    SET field_1 = table_b.field_1
    WHERE table_a.field_2=table_b.field_2
      AND table_a.field_3=table_b.field_3 
      AND table_a.field_4=table_b.field_4
      AND table_a.field_5=table_b.field_5
```

Comment: @shadow how can you close a question with two answer?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you can edit the list of duplicate questions after hammering with a single one.